# Not able to pull zeppelin-server image

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-zeppelin

I am using Docker On Mac with K8 and trying to install Zeppelin on K8 so as to try out Spark jobs.

I am following https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-SNAPSHOT/quickstart/kubernetes.html and got stuck at the first step itself

On executing `kubectl apply -f zeppelin-server.yaml`,I am getting:

```
NAME                                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
zeppelin-server-7cddf7f7bf-gxc2q                 2/3     ImagePullBackOff   0          16s
```

Events:

[image]

I have not modified anything in the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be an inconsistency between the [Zeppelin image published on Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/u/zeppelin) and the Zeppelin image referenced in the [config file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/zeppelin/master/k8s/zeppelin-server.yaml) on the Zeppelin homepage.

With [this commit](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/commit/90bfb7209bc74470e2cc33a0b71369d2e473e2f6#diff-ff3de7f03fa72c16dc83aa18c00d725d0f6318774bba6adc01ea45242c2740dc) the image in the config file has been changed from `zeppelin` to `zeppelin-server` (as well as some other changes have been implemented). It looks like that the new image has not yet been pushed to Docker hub.

To get the Zeppelin deployment running using the config file from the Zeppelin homepage, try to change three lines in the config file:

- line 32: the name of the published image is `apache/zeppelin:0.9.0`. This name can be seen [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/zeppelin/tags).
- line 33: `ZEPPELIN_HOME` should be set to `/zeppelin`. This corresponds to the value of `Z_HOME` in the [Docker file](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/zeppelin/dockerfile) of the image.
- line 177: the image name should be corrected here too and set to `apache/zeppelin:0.9.0`

Another option would be to revert to an older version of the [config file](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/commits/master/k8s/zeppelin-server.yaml).

Comment: thanks @werner. After the changes, Zeppelin is deployed but running a sample Spark code is leading to "org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.io.IOException: Interpreter process is not running
null" Have created a new question for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65416343/getting-org-apache-zeppelin-interpreter-interpreterexception-java-io-ioexcepti

Comment: ZEPPELIN_HOME  should stay as same /opt/zeppelin

Comment: `It looks like that the new image has not yet been pushed to Docker hub.` Well, 11 months later, it still hasn't been published.

Comment: Almost 2 years have passed after that change! Either it was a wrong commit that should be reverted or the image should be pushed with the `zeppelin-server` name. You cannot have k8s support where the very first `apply` fails and must be followed by hours of confusion!

Answer (score 0):

I've found this being tracked as [ZEPPELIN-5191](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-5191), it provides some background for this topic and a call for a documentation improvement PR.