# Getting "org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.io.IOException: Interpreter process is not running null"

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-zeppelin

Hi I am on Docker on mac[K8 enabled] and trying to deploy Zeppelin on K8 by following https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-SNAPSHOT/quickstart/kubernetes.html.

After deploying the zeppelin server on K8, I am trying to run the Spark example but getting following exception:

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.io.IOException: Interpreter process is not running
null
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:134)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:281)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:412)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:72)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:130)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Interpreter process is not running
null
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:163)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:131)
    ... 13 more
```

Spark interpreter status is green

[image]

Interpreter is binded

[image]

What should I check to know why it is failing?

Comment: Did you find a solution?